# Azure proxies don't accept query string parameters as request overrides

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to call my azure proxy function with query string parameters. 
I don't want to pass my params as route parameters, I want to do it with query string params as to not break my current contract.

My url is as follows `https:/<mrUrl>.net/api/address-suggestions`

I then have some static request overrides parameters that work fine.

Lastly I call the api as `https:/<mrUrl>.net/api/address-suggestions?limit=10&query=main`

In my proxies.json I have

```
"requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.method": "get",
                "backend.request.querystring.api-version": "1.0",
                "backend.request.querystring.countrySet": "US",
                "backend.request.querystring.typeahead": "true",
                "backend.request.querystring.query": "{query}",
                "backend.request.querystring.limit": "{limit}"
            }
```

That seems to be the only way to do what I want, but my response is always "query parameter is missing or empty" (note if I hard code the query in the JSON it works). Am I to assume there is no support for send query string params and only support for route params?

Answer (score 1):

I found it for anyone looking. Use `request.querystring.<yourQuerystringName>`